# Is there a way to allow acess to an specific device that is out of my network?

Tags: linux, iptables, centos6.5

I’m trying to allow my mobile device to connect from everywhere, Wi-Fi or not to an specific port of my Linux server which is running a `webmin` service.

I’m using `iptables` to set some rules to which IP addresses can connect to that port for example my house.

I don’t what any other device or IP to connect to my server's `webmin` service so I drop every other connection with the `iptables`. Also my house `ipadress` changes every now and then and this is a problem since I have to update the rule as a result.

However I wish to connect through my phone with mobile data or Wi-Fi.

The MAC address isn't an option since the device will be changing internet connections and this is undetectable through browser.

So the questions is, is there a way to identify an specific device request to let it access or not to my server?

Comment: **“The MAC address isn't an option since the device will be changing internet connections and this is undetectable through browser.”** What do browsers have to do with `iptables`? I posted an answer showing how `iptables` and be used to handle MAC address filtering. Pretty cool stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You can use SSH to either set up a [tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) or a [SOCKS proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS).
2. You can set up a VPN service on your router and configure your mobile device to sign into the VPN, giving you access to your private network.
3. You can set up a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) and set up authentication through it, using either password or key based authentication.
4. You can set up [port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking).

Using a SOCKS proxy over SSH is the simplest solution.  If you eventually want to have more access to your network (not just HTTP access) then a VPN solution would be a great way to go.

Comment: A VPN is the best way to go.  Near-native performance, allows all protocols, full access, authentication, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This required type of technique is called [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking):

> In computer networking, port knocking is a method of externally
>   opening ports on a firewall by generating a connection attempt on a
>   set of prespecified closed ports. Once a correct sequence of
>   connection attempts is received, the firewall rules are dynamically
>   modified to allow the host which sent the connection attempts to
>   connect over specific port(s).